# Android: String class's equals method behave abruptly

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I am reading a text file and from that I am inserting a value suppose ID=1s001(String) in the data base.
And I am again reading files but this time I want to make sure that I read files if the  ID is different in these file, for that I am reterving value from db and comparing with current ID.

Like this
Id (from deb). equals (current ID)

But unfortunatily even if the ID=1s001 equals method returns false.

only thing I was able to find is that currentID.length=6 & Id (from deb).length is returning 5. I don't know what is causing this? any Idea?

Actual Code:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(StorageDataBase, allColumns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        if(count>0){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                String slsManCode=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sales_man_id"));
                System.out.println(slsManCode.length()+"            "+salesManCode.length());
                boolean is=slsManCode.trim().equals(salesManCode.trim());

                                if(slsManCode.contains(salesManCode))
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

Every coloumn in db is text.

Comment: That might be because of some extra space. Try `id.trim().equals(currentId.trim())`

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: Can you eyeball the string values? Say from within the debugger or by writing them to logcat. Do they look the same?

Comment: @NigelK : The value I have taken as example are the real values. and yes they do look same to me atleast.

Comment: Try slsManCode.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(salesManCode.trim());

Comment: Have you tried watching their values in debugger?

Comment: Try converting the string to a char[] using .toCharArray(). Then iterate over that array in the debugger so you can examine each character in turn. At the very least, that should tell you which position has the unwanted character which you can then trim or substring off.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured what was causing so, actually it was an Encoding issue.